# How to query for non-matching records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to create a query that finds those members with no reviews.

Table 1 - items selected
member/audno
733 12
733 13
733 14
844 12
844 13
844 14
955 12
955 13
955 14

Table 2 - reviews
member/audno/reviewno
733 12  111
844 13  112
955 14  113

Create new query with results of members with items with no reviews:
member/audno
733 13
733 14
844 12
844 14
955 12
955 13

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM
    items_selected I
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            reviews R
        WHERE
            R.member = I.member AND R.audno = I.audno
    )
```

Another, equivalent query is based on a left join

```
SELECT I.*
FROM
    items_selected I
    LEFT JOIN reviews R
        ON I.member = R.member AND I.audno = R.audno
WHERE
    R.member IS NULL
```

You might test both of them and look which one is more performant.

Comment: Neither of these is correct MS Access syntax (at least by default).  Although the answer is right in spirit, that makes it hard to upvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have created the two tables in Access and entered the two queries exactly as shown above. Both of them work as expected! Why do you think this is not correct Access syntax?

Comment: I didn't try first option but I did successfully use the left join option. Worked perfectly! Thanks Olivier.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes . . . You must have ANSI mode turned on.

Comment: I have **not** set the option "SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)" in my DB; however, the queries still work. ANSI-89 is the default format for new DBs (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/set-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070486.aspx).